# Perl compile time error, uninitialized value

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, initialization

I have been having a problem with perl. This is my program:

```
my $data = decode_json $json;
my @infoids = keys %{$data -> {listinginfo}};

foreach my $infoid (@infoids) {
my $price = $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price};
print "$price" . "\n"; #30
}
```

I am using strict and warnings, I am getting the error: Use of uninitialized value $price in string at C:\Users\Seb\perl.pl line 30. Any help as to why this is happening would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Seb

EDIT:
Im using this code to login to the website, I think it may be faulty. It doesnt return any errors but is not logging me in successfully.

```
my $login = "https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=market%2F";
my $username = "USR";
my $password = "PASS";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($login);
$mech->form_name('loginForm');
$mech->field(login => $username);
$mech->field(passwd => $password);
$mech->click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this expression `$data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price};` is not initialized. Try 
`my $price = defined $data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price} ?$data -> {listinginfo}{$infoid}{converted_price} : 0 ;`
This is the short form of if .. then .. else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I do that I get just lots of 0's. Do you have any idea why this is?